# Pyspark dynamic column selection from dataframe

Tags: dataframe, select, pyspark, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe with multiple columns as t_orno,t_pono, t_sqnb ,t_pric,....and so on(it's a table with multiple columns).
The 2nd dataframe contains certain name of the columns from 1st dataframe. Eg.

```
columnname
t_pono
t_pric
:
:
```

I need to select only those columns from the 1st dataframe whose name is present in the 2nd. In above example t_pono,t_pric.

How can this be done?

Comment: seems fairly easy. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the following columns (which can be obtained using [`df.columns`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.columns.html), which returns a list):

```
df1_cols = ["t_orno", "t_pono", "t_sqnb", "t_pric"]
df2_cols = ["columnname", "t_pono", "t_pric"]
```

To get only those columns from the first dataframe that are present in the second one, you can do set intersection (and I cast it to a list, so it can be used to select data):

```
list(set(df1_cols).intersection(df2_cols))
```

And we get the result:

```
["t_pono", "t_pric"]
```

To put it all together and select only those columns:

```
select_columns = list(set(df1_cols).intersection(df2_cols))

new_df = df1.select(*select_columns)
```

Comment: Little twisting in the file and it worked...thanks :)